# How to input the following data in prolog?

Tags: prolog

```
not(A()) and not(D()) and not(B()) and not(A()).
```

What's the right way?

Comment: What's the context of the question?

Answer (score 1):

The concept of **logical negation** is already included in Prolog in means of failure. If your implementation doesn't supply it (it can happens) you can think `not` as

```
not(P) :- call(P), !, fail.
```

or

```
not(P) :- (call(P) -> fail ; true)
```

Then look at the formula, it can be simplified to have `not` applied just to single predicates:

```
~(A & ~D) & ~B & ~A = (~A | D) & ~B & ~A = ~A & ~B
```

It's just a **De Morgan law** and a consideration about the fact that `D` isn't useful to satisfability of the predicate.

then you can combine them:

```
final_predicate :- not(B), not(A).
```

**EDIT:** remember `,` is AND and `;` is OR.

Answer (score 1):

If simply trying to evaluate a propositional logic statement using PROLOG, you could try the following. Start with an encoding of the values of your 'propositions' `a`, `b` and `d`, such as:

`a :- true. % this means that a is true.`

`b :- fail. % this means that b is false`

...etc. For example, assuming your statements were:

```
a :- fail.
b :- fail.
d :- fail.
```

Then, executing your statement:

```
?- not(a), not(b), not(d), not(a).
true.
```

n.b.: The 'propositions' encoded here are 'simulated' - they're actually zero arity first-order predicates as far as PROLOG is concerned.

ps. `a :- true.` can be simplified to `a.`.

pps. If I'm way off the mark and you're after a way of symbolically manipulating the statement into some other form, such as a normalization, then you need to write what is called a *meta-interpreter* in PROLOG. Refer to [Clocksin and Mellish's Programming in Prolog, Appendix B, 'Clausal Form Program Listings'](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=lbcXj6GbMoQC&lpg=PA271&dq=clocksin%20mellish%20clausal%20form%20program%20listings&pg=PA271#v=onepage&q=&f=false), which might help you.